# Type Providers - Could I generate a type at compilation-time that decorates all methods of a type somehow?

Tags: f#, metaprogramming, type-providers

I've read about the great capabilities of Type Providers, such as static-typing when querying JSON documents, so I can imagine that I can create what I have in my mind at the moment, with this technology.

Let's say I want to allow a consumer of my TypeProvider-library Foo a way to create a type Bar, which will have the following pre-condition for each of their methods: check the mutable state of a `boolean disposed` field, if it's true, throw an ObjectDisposedException.

Would this be possible? How could one define such an implementation of this high-level type creator?

Comment: You might be able to hack together something that works to a degree, but in general, type providers aren't really good for that kind of metaprogramming. Most notably, in assembly A you could only provide it for types declared in assemblies other than A - since type providers can't access information about types in the assembly they're running in.

Answer (score 7):

A couple of years back Keith Battocchi published a project called [ILBuilder](https://github.com/kbattocchi/ILBuilder). Among other things ILBuilder contains a method type provider in [ILBuilder.fs](https://github.com/kbattocchi/ILBuilder/blob/master/ILBuilder.fs) that provides methods for types in mscorlib, e.g.

```
MethodProvider.Methods.System.Console.``WriteLine : string*obj->unit`
```

It is possible you could use this as a starting point for a type provider that wraps classes from another assembly and provides methods.

Another option might be to consider Ross McKinlay's [Mixin Type Provider](http://www.pinksquirrellabs.com/post/2015/03/01/Introducing-The-Mixin-Type-Provider.aspx) that (ab)uses F#'s Type Provider mechanism to provide meta-programming capabilities.

Yet another option might be to use [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/), [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) etc. to do IL weaving, or code generation via reflection to build proxy classes.

That said probably the lowest friction solution would be to create a function that checks for disposal and manually add it to each member.